# Finding the dimension of the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the linear map $f:M_n(\Bbb{F}) \rightarrow M_n(\Bbb{F})$ defined by $$f(A)=\frac{A-A^T}{2}$$
>
> Determine the kernel of $f$ and its dimension

I know the kernel is where the transpose of $A$ is equal to the negative of $A$ but how do I then find it's dimension?

Comment: for kernel $A^T=A$ (not $-A$). **hint:** So you are looking for symmetric matrices.

Comment: $\Big\{ A_{ij} : 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n \Big\}$ is a basis for $\text{ker}\;f$ where $A_{ij}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix having $1$ in the ith row and jth column, $1$ in the j th row and ith column, and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the kernel is where $A=A^T$. So it's the space of all symmetric matrices of size $n$. To create such a matrix you need to choose only the values for the entries on the main diagonal and above the main diagonal. (and because the matrix is symmetric that will give you the rest of the entries). So you need to choose $n$ values for the first row, $n-1$ for the second row and so on. The dimension is $1+2+3+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Of course formally you need to show that there exists a basis of that size.

Comment: Thank you, I got ahead of myself with the negative sign.  I can prove it now.